# how fix the error in MS acess VBA Code 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to fix following error I have create one issue when I type `Me.Salary.RowSource` the not showing `.RowSource` in drop list if I type manually `Me.Salary.RowSource` then not work code how to fix it 
and also not showing `me.salary.Itemdata` what I do kindly help me thanks.

```
Me.Salary.RowSource = "SELECT SalaryPM FROM" & _
       " Employees WHERE ID = " & Me.EmployeeID & _
       " Order BY ID"
Me.Salary Me.Salary.ItemData(0)
```

Comment: Run the query in a test query to see if it produces the list you expect to see.

Comment: Show the query that you type manually and that works.

Comment: Line `Me.Salary Me.Salary.ItemData(0)` makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?